How to include the UIBackgroundModes entitlement into Provisioning profile?
I am facing such error:
"Automatic signing failed
Xcode failed to provision this target."
"Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: org.reactjs.native.example.hmp-wheels" doesn't include the UIBackgroundModes entitlement."
Error from xcode:

https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers has no "UIBackgroundModes entitlement" therefore I physically can't enable it. Left image on screenshot is from xcode, right from the website. The item is missing on the website
Screenshot:

xcode:

So my question is how to solve such problem? Manual signing gives no effect. But "Push Notifications" when added in xcode was successfully checked in "Capabilities" section on https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers.
Thank you.
[upd1]


This seems like a specifically react native issue (and should be tagged as such). The background modes you've shown in the screen shots are the background modes, and you can confirm in the info.plist that they are set.

Also you say manual signing gives no effect, but you are not showing that in the screen shot; the screen shot is using automatic signing.

I don't understand how it is related to react native if option is physically missing on their (apple) page?

Yeah, I guess you already saw this. https://github.com/NativeScript/firebase/issues/221 I'm guessing you're the last message in that thread (same screenshots, elementary my dear watson).

Yes, but i guess missing token is a result of a problem of this UIbackground error. And again, this identifier is missing on apple page. I dont think I am that special one and people somehow find the solution. But how, if there is no such option. Or i dont understand something which is likely true.

After days of trying I managed to solve the problem. Removed all capabilities, cleaned abandoned ones in file .entitlements with key UIBackgroundModes, cleaned xcode cache, build cache and restarted cxcode. Enabled all back again and the error is gone. Apple developer support could not help either. Unexplainable error that should not have happened.
